# JWT is added in lazyUpdate field instead of headers Angular 14

Tags: angular, jwt, http-headers, angular-http-interceptors

I'm implementing JWT RefreshToken. When jwt is expired, a refreshTokenfunction to generate new tokens executes in the Interceptor  to generate new tokens, and new tokens are generated from **server** and stored in broswer localstrorage at Angular Side. After that I'm passing the new accesstoken in the headers to get user profile. But the new accesstoken is going in the **lazyUpdate** field instead of **headers field** in HttpHeaders. And I think because of that the interceptor is not repeating the request to get user profile on the bases of new jwt token. Because after new tokens being added in the localstorage, the request to get user profile from interceptor is not made.

**RefAccessAfter Console log**

[image]

**HERE THE NEW JWT ACCESS TOKEN SHOULD BE ATTACHED IN HEADERS. BUT IT'S GOING IN LazyUpdate**

```
  const authRequest = this.addTokenHeader(
    req,
    this.newTokens.Tokens.accessToken
  );

  console.log('RefAccessAfter', authRequest);

  return next.handle(authRequest);
```

**service function to generate new tokens after first token is expired**

```
token: string | null = localStorage.getItem('refreshtoken');

  public async refreshToken(): Promise<Token> {
    const header = new HttpHeaders().set(
      'Authorization',
      'Bearer ' + this.token!
    );
    let res = this.http.get<Token>(`${this.url}/authentication/refresh`, {
      headers: header,
    });

    let data = await lastValueFrom(res);

    return data;
  }
```

**Interceptor code**

```
 newTokens!: Token;

  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const accesstoken = this.authService.getAccessToken();
    const accessTokenExpired = this.authService.accessTokenExpired();
    let authRequest = req;

    if (accesstoken && !accessTokenExpired) {
      authRequest = this.addTokenHeader(req, accesstoken);
      console.log('AccessAfter', authRequest);
    }

    return next.handle(authRequest).pipe(
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (error.status === 401) {

          this.handleRefToken(req, next);
        }
        return throwError(error);
      })
    );
  }
```

**Token Refresh Function in interceptor**

```
  async handleRefToken(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    const accessTokenExpired = this.authService.accessTokenExpired();
    const accesstoken = this.authService.getAccessToken();
    let refreshtoken = localStorage.getItem('refreshtoken');

    if (refreshtoken) {
      this.newTokens = await this.authService.refreshToken();
      console.log(this.newTokens);

      localStorage.setItem('accesstoken', this.newTokens.Tokens.accessToken);
      localStorage.setItem('refreshtoken', this.newTokens.Tokens.refreshToken);

      const authRequest = this.addTokenHeader(
        req,
        this.newTokens.Tokens.accessToken
      );

      console.log('RefAccessAfter', authRequest);

      return next.handle(authRequest);

    }
    return throwError('BAC');
  }
```

**Add token in requests function in interceptor**

```
  addTokenHeader(request: HttpRequest<any>, token: string | null) {
    return request.clone({
      headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token!),
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

**The token is attached in lazyupdate because I'm not subscribing the Observable.**

**Observables don't fire until they're subscribed. And because of that the request was not made**

So the answer is following of my particular case

**change this**

```
 return next.handle(authRequest);
```

**To this**

```
return next.handle(authRequest).subscribe();
```